# Work Permits for Digital Nomads: Any Countries with Remote Job Offers, No Employment History Required?

Tags: digital-nomads

I've been researching digital nomad work permits lately. It appears that, in every country, it is typically required to demonstrate a work history with your current employer for a few months before applying for the work permit. However, I'm interested to know if there are any countries that have the provision to grant work permits solely based on a remote job offer, without the need for providing evidence of several months of employment with the company, regardless of the applicant's nationality?

Comment: It feels like you're conflating a couple of different concepts here. A country typically issues a work permit for you to come to that country and work for an employer based in that country. It's not really relevant whether the job is remote or on-site. Some countries are starting to offer "digital-nomad visas", but that's a completely different concept to a traditional work-permit/visa. Countries which might offer a digital-nomad visa want to enssure that you do have a reliable income so as to be able to support yourself while living there, so require you to show employment history.